# react 17.0.2 Unexpected token <>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I upgrade the react version from 16 to 17. But i have the <> element to render a bunch of elements and now with the upgrade is not working. Is <> not allowed anymore?

```
    ./src/components/NavBar.js
Syntax error: C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/wesy_webapp/src/components/NavBar.js: Unexpected token (1068:13)

      {currentUser ? (
         <>
          ^
          <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchField}>
           <div className={classes.searchIcon} id="searchicon"
```

Comment: That should still be allowed. Are you sure you're running the compiled js file, and not this jsx file directly? That would be another reason why you're getting a syntax error.

Comment: Likely has nothing to do with the Fragment component itself, that just happens to be the first JSX token it ran into.

Comment: Try renaming the file from `.js` to `.jsx`

Comment: Following the idea from @Federkun, try to change files where you use react to `.jsx` or `.tsx`, be sure that you are importing `react`.